# call nodejs function recursively in settimeout with callback

Tags: node.js

I am trying to call nodejs function recursively in setTimeout with callback. Code snippet attached. It is not working as expected. Am I missing anything?

```
Model.xyz= function(cb){
    //do something here and get the result.
    if(result<10)
    {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            Model.xyz(cb);
        },5000);
    }

    //once result is > 10 execute following code
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? What is the expected vs the actual behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use async lib that will forever call Your method

```
const async = require('async');

Model.xyz = cb => {
    // do somethings
    if(result < 10) return cb(null, true);
    cb();
}

async.forever(cb => {
  Model.xyz(repeat => {
    // finish call and schedule next call
    if(repeat === true) return setTimeout(cb, 5000);
    cb('exit');
  });
});
```